# In commutativity theorems in ring theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, ac.commutative-algebra, noncommutative-rings

Suppose that $R$ is a ring such that for any $x\in R$ there exists $1<n(x)\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x^{n(x)}-x\in Z(R)$. Prove that $R$ is commutative or if it is not commutative, then the ideal generated by all additive commutators is null.

I wanted to prove it like Jacobson-Herstein theorem. So if the assertion is true for division rings, from density and subdirect product representation theorems, I can prove it for left primitive rings and next for semiprimitive rings. But I can't prove it for division rings and arbitrary rings from semiprimitive rings.

Comment: Of course, the JH theorem shows that $R/Z(R)$ is commutative.  What do you mean by "the ideal generated by all additive commutators is null", if not that it is the 0 ideal (and hence that the ring is commutative)?

Comment: Suppose that $A=\{ ab-ba : a,b\in R\}$. $I=<x :x\in A>$, the ideal generated by the elements of $A$ or $I= ‎\cap‎ J$ where $A‎\subseteq‎ J$ and $J$ is an ideal of $R$. We should show that $I$ is null. Yes, $R$ is commutative if and only if $I=0$ and in this case $I$ is null. Of course in general we should prove that $I$ is null.

Comment: My question is what 'null' means of an ideal (since it doesn't seem to mean "equals the 0 ideal").  EDIT:  Maybe it means 'nilpotent'?

Comment: An ideal $I$ is null, means every element of $I$ is nilpotent. Of course every nilpotent ideal is null. But the converse is not true.